# ASP.Net How do I get the base URL without HttpRequest?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, azure

I am trying to get the base URL from the worker role. I can't get it from there.

How do I get the base URL in this situation?

I have found this property:

```
Application.Current.Host.Source
```

but, in order for this to work, I need the reference System.Windows.dll which is in the Silverlight folder. Since I am not using Silverlight for this part of the application I am not sure if I should use it here or find another way.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to find the external URL of your app?  (Like something.cloudapp.net?)  If so, there isn't a good way to do this from within a Windows Azure application (without calling out to the Service Management API and looking up the deployment by ID).

Comment: OK smarx, but how do we call out the service management API? If you can leave here a link about it I appreciate. Thumbs up. Thanks.

Comment: Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460799.aspx, but be sure to check out csmanage.exe (and corresponding .NET library) here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazuresamples.

Note that it may be simpler to just put the domain name in a config setting if that's an option for you.